# SQL joined tables are causing duplicates

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

So table A is an overall table of `policy_id` information, while table b is `policy_id`'s with claims attached. Not all of the id's in A exist in B, but I want to join the two tables and sum(total claims).

The issue is that the sum is way higher than the actual sum within the table itself.

Here is what I've tried so far:

```
select a.policy_id, coalesce(sum(b.claim_amt), 0)
from database.table1 as a
left join database2.table2 as b on a.policy_id = b.policy_id
where product_code = 'CI'
group by a.policy_id
```

The id's that don't exist in b show up just fine with a 0 next to them, it's the ones that do exist where the claim_amt's seem like they're being duplicated heavily in the sum.

Comment: Is `policy_id` the primary key of the first table? If it is not unique in that table, you can expect figures to be double counted.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: You were told on posting to use a more specific DBMS tag than 'sql'. Give DBMS name & version.

Comment: This seems a common error where people want some joins, each possibly involving a different key, of some subqueries, each possibly involving join and/or aggregation, but they erroneously try to do all the joining then all the aggregating or to aggregate over previous aggregations. Write separate aggregations over appropriate rows and/or aggregate a case statement picking rows; join on a unique column set. Sometimes DISTINCT aggregation picks the right values after a non-key join. (A join on a non-key of either of 2 input tables can give multiple output rows for each key of each input table.)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect your `policy_id` in `table1` are not unique and that leads to the doubled,tripled ,etc. amounts
You could aggregate the sums from `table2` in a CTE to get around this.

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT
  policy_id
  coalesce(sum(claim_amt), 0) as sum_amt
FROM database2.table2 
group by policy_id
)
select a.policy_id, b.sum_amt
from database.table1 as a
left join CTE as b on a.policy_id = b.policy_id
where product_code = 'CI'
```